# I'm getting undefined variable instead of displaying the error message

Tags: codeigniter, email, tankauth

I created a callback function for email validation in codeigniter using tank auth. Here are my codes:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email|callback_is_email_domain[gmail.com,yahoo.com]');

function is_email_domain($input, $domain='') 
{
    $email_domain=explode("@", $input);
    $domain = explode(",", $domain);
    if(in_array($email_domain[1],$domain))
    {
      $result=1;
    }

    else
    {
       $this->form_validation->set_message('is_email_domain', 'The %s field must be a %s email address');
    }

   return $result;
}
```

I want tank auth to allow only 'gmail.com' and 'yahoo.com' emails to register on my website.

Thank you so much!

Comment: what is the undefined variable?

Comment: @Menuka - the $result variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$email_domain is not an array but you have use it as an array `$email_domain[1]`
```